# Spring-boot ResponseEntity body missing for non-200 status codes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

***TLDR;*** How can I send a text message in the body along with a 304 status code using Spring `ResponseEntity` ?

**Context**

I am writing a REST API with Spring-boot. In some endpoints, I want to return:

- either status `200 OK` with body `Success`,
- or status `304 NOT MODIFIED` with body `Not modified.`

My endpoints use `ResponseEntity` (in kotlin) in the following way:

```
@PutMapping("/test")
fun modifyStuff(): ResponseEntity<String> {
    if (someCondition)
        // "not modified" not sent in the body
        return ResponseEntity("not modified", HttpStatus.NOT_MODIFIED)

    // using OK, it works
    return ResponseEntity("success", HttpStatus.OK)
}
```

**Problem**

Whenever I create a `ResponseEntity` with a status code != 200, the body is not sent (empty body). Changing the `HttpStatus` to `OK` makes the message show again... I don't want to create error handlers for not modified, as this is definitely not an error.

Comment: Per [Http specification](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) 304 response should not have a body.

Answer (score 0):

Earlier there was earlier standard RFC2616 and now you can refer to newer **RFC 7230-7237** and both of them mention 304 response should not include body.

Specifically older RFC2616 says it "must not include body" and newer RFC7230 "All 1xx (Informational), 204 (No Content), and **304 (Not Modified) responses do not include a message body**"
In the end some servers might send or accept body with this status but it is not the case for spring ResponseEntity.